# Sails.js server request timeout

Tags: sails.js

I am using sails.js  v0.10.5.
I have long processing controller action which takes more than 2 minutes to complete which causes the sails server to timeout. How can I overwrite this timeout duration and set it to my value say 10 minutes.Please specify in which file and what changes I need to make to increase the sails server timeout.

Answer (score 4):

You can find which action delay the starting process

```
sails  --verbose lift
```

most of the time, ORM causes this kind of issue.

**UPDATE**
i think the timeout is provided by Express, if you want to modify it, you can use `connect-time`

1.install

```
$ npm install connect-timeout --save
```

2.add middleware to **http.js**

```
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
......
order: [ 'timeout' ....]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Wu, but I need to increase the timeout duration from 2 minutes to 10 minutes.Since the call require this much time for processing. I have achieved it by following code in controller
`var myAction= function(req,res){
 req.connection.setTimeout(10*60*1000);
       // action code/processing 
       res.ok(jsonData)
}
`
But I have to write it for every action.I there any configutaion option to overite timeout globally.

Comment: Still didn't find a way to override timeout globally...
Tried the http.js changes in the middleware (but NO success).

Is there an other solution ?

Answer (score 4):

My answer is pretty similar to the provided by Ryan, but I'll expand the example a bit more for clarity. Also I don't see the need for the dependency installation there.

TL;DR Add a custom middleware that amends `req` to increase the timeout

In `/config/http.js`

```
order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'myRequestLogger',
  'contentTypeCheck',
  'extendTimeout', // <--- The order is somewhat important, added it before the body is parsed without issue
  'bodyParser',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
],

extendTimeout: function(req, res, next) {
  req.setTimeout(300 * 1000); // Increase the request timeout to 5 minutes

  return next();
},
// Other custom middleware
```

Can also set `req.setTimeout(0)` if you don't want any timeout at all, but could be a bit risky.

This will set the timeout for all routes keep in mind. This can be overridden on a per route basis by simply setting `req.setTimeout(<some timeout>)` as the first line in the controller handling the route

Answer (score 1):

yjimk, thanks for your idea... it wasn't working for me first, but I found a solution.

Problem was in extendTimeout function, here is the fixed version:

```
extendTimeout: (function () {
  console.log('Initializing `extendTimeout`...');

  return function (req, res, next) {
    sails.log.info('extendTimeout to 1h');
    req.setTimeout(3600000);

    return next();
  };
})(),
```